# Search for multiple files with different file extensions (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, bash, logging

I have been trying to use Python 3 to search the root filesystem for different file extensions such as .mp3, .mp4, .png, .jpg, and other media types.

I have been successful in doing this using bash:

```
find / -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.flv' -o -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.wmv' -o -name '*.mov' -o -name '*.png' -o -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.tif' -o -name '*.gif' -o -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.wmv' -o -name '*.wma' -o -name '*.aif' -o -name '*.jar'
```

And I have been able to use that code with the use of `subprocess.call(command.split(command))`

But I would rather not use bash commands with my python code if I can help it.

I have been successful in the use of this code

```
with open('logTest.txt', 'a+') as f:
    os.chdir('/')
    for file in glob.iglob('**/*.mp3', recursive=True):
        f.write(file + '\n')
        print(file)
```

This would open the logging file and successfully find all .mp3 files starting from the root file system. But as you can probably figure out, it does not find any other media file types.
I would like to able to do this in python3. I have looked around on stack overflow and I have seen other examples, but they never seem to do what I want them to do. They either don't run or print anything out, or they do work but only for one file extension at a time.

Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated.

(sorry if this question is repeated a lot)

Comment: Take a look at `os.walk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately with `glob` you can't match multiple extensions in the one pass. You have to merge the results from separate calls.

As *Poshi* suggested, try using [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.walk).

The following code iterates over every file in every directory, and checks if the filename ends in any of the extensions.

```py
import os

extensions = ('.jpg', '.mp4', '.flv', '.avi', '.wmv', '.mov', '.png', '.tif', 
              '.gif', '.mp3', '.wma', '.aif', '.jar')

with open('logTest.txt', 'a+') as f:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
        for filename in files:
            if any(filename.endswith(extension) for extension in extensions):
                filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                f.write(filepath + '\n')
                print(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

```python
extensions = [".png", ".svg", ".jpeg", ".pdf", ".tex"]

output_exists = False

for extension in extensions:

    output_exists = output_exists and any(
        [file.exists for file in output_path.rglob(f"**/*{extension}")]
    )
```